# How can I use CSS nth-child(odd) nth-child(even) to justify columns in a CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid. I would like to use the `nth-child` `odd` and `even` selectors to make items be pushed up against each vertical edge of the grid - it should look like:

[image]

```css
.questionsAndAnswers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  justify-items: end;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.questionsAndAnswers:nth-child(odd){
  justify-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionsAndAnswers">
  <p>
    one
  </p>
  <p>
    two
  </p>
  <p>
    three
  </p>
  <p>
    four
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close - use `nth-child` / `nth-type` pseudo selector on the child `<p>`-elements instead, and use `justify-self` instead of `justify-items`.

```css
.questionsAndAnswers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-of-type(even){
  justify-self: end;
}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-of-type(odd){
  justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionsAndAnswers">
  <p>
    one
  </p>
  <p>
    two
  </p>
  <p>
    three
  </p>
  <p>
    four
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.questionsAndAnswers

{

```
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 grid-gap: 24px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: "sans-serif";
 border: 1px solid red;
```

}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(1)

{

```
 grid-row: 1;
 grid-column: 1;
```

}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(2)

{

```
 grid-row: 1;
 grid-column: 2;
```

}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(3)

{

```
 grid-row: 2;
 grid-column: 1;
```

}

.questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(4)

{

```
 grid-row: 2;
 grid-column: 2;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```css
.questionsAndAnswers {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     grid-gap: 24px;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: "sans-serif";
     border: 1px solid red;
}
 .questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(1){
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 1;
}
 .questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(2){
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 2;
}
 .questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(3){
     grid-row: 2;
     grid-column: 1;
}
 .questionsAndAnswers p:nth-child(4){
     grid-row: 2;
     grid-column: 2;
}
```

Comment: Answers should include some explanation of code they contain. Code-only answers are rarely helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).